# How to easily and smoothly get data from data which should be of MediaType.JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, rest, media-type

Is it a nice practice to retrieve a JSON object as a String and then parse it manually inside the application or there is a better way to get a transfer object representation (eg. some tools or comfortable APIs, automated mapping services, don't know)?

```
Example:
    @POST
    @Path("/myUrlPath")
    public Response postSomething(String jsonAsString) {
        JSON json = getFromMyCustomParser(jsonAsString);
        MyObject myObject = getFromMyCustomMapper(json);
        //business logic    
}
```

Don't know much about this topic.

Comment: Consider using Jackson, gson or org.json.JSONObject (and as a atomated mapper between objects try Dozer).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually accept a JSON as a parameter of your resource method. The Jersey REST API would support this. You might have to add a JSON library as a dependency.

I think that this is the JSON dependency we use:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
     <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
     <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

In this case we use the JSONObject class from org.codehaus.jettison.json.

There's a [tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html) on how to do this using the Jersey framework. It explains POJO mapping which is based on Jackson. You may have to configure POJO mapping yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Heres an example for Jackson:**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Something("Name")));

public class Something {
    private String name;
    public Something(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output: {"name":"Name"}

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Further reading: [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

**Example for org.json.JSONObject:**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Hello");
list.add("Hello2");
list.add("Hello3");
json.put("List", list);

System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output: {"List":["Hello","Hello2","Hello3"]}

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```

Further reading: [JSON.org](http://json.org/java/)

**Example for GSON** 
(https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples)

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
    private int value1 = 1;
    private String value2 = "abc";
    private transient int value3 = 3;
    BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
    }
}
```

Serialization

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Deserialization

```
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
```

Output: {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}

Further reading: [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)